# Symfony 3.2 form bindings with json request

Tags: php, json, forms, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3.2, and have a little bit of a problem on inserting the JSON data into forms. I have my Note entity, that I need to validate using forms, but I keep getting the error

> Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\Note as array

All I am doing is creating a named builder form, and submitting with a JSON object that I previously decoded, so it's an array now. This is the code:

```
$note = new Note();
$form = $this->get('form.factory')
    ->createNamedBuilder('noteForm', FormType::class, $note)
    ->add('type', TextType::class, [
        'required' => true
    ])
    ->add('title', TextType::class, [
        'required' => true
    ])
    ->add('content', TextType::class, [
        'required' => true
    ])
    ->getForm()
;

$form->submit($data);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // ...
}
```

I also tried with the regular FormBuilder, and I made acustom form class, but none of that works, and I keep getting the same error. And yes, I am sending data as a json object:

```
{noteForm: {type: "note", title: "something", content: "something"}}
```

**$data** declaration is:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please show the declaration of `$data` so we can validate how it is being set for consumption by the form.

Comment: @fyrye I edited it in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i'm a little bit confused, the problem was that i was sending the $data to a different function and that function is the one in the question above, and i put the @return Note annotation as well. I'm not sure, why it can't work that way, so if anyone can point out for me where i'm wrong. Also one other thing i was mistaken about was sending API call to symfony form. I read on other threads that i had to pass the form name as well as the form fields, but in profiler it said "The form should not contain extra fields", so i just edited the json request, so that it doesn't have form name, only fields, and it's working now. JSON object that i was sending now looks like this: 
`{type: "note", title: "something", content: "something"}`
I guess that means that you dont have to send form name anymore in Symfony 3.2?
Still i get the CSRF token invalid error, but i don't know how to work that out, except removing CSRF validation from forms.
Thanks again, and sorry if this has been a lame question, but i'm a beginner in symfony. :)

Edit:
I figured it out, i don't know why i'm writing this, but if anyone comes across this, it may be helpfull. So, there was a piece of code inside of `$form->isValid()`, and that piece of code was the following: `$formData = $form->getData();
$note->setType($formData['type']);
...`
And the error was "Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\Note as array". The thing i was doing was exactly that i was treating $formData as an array, when in reality, $formData was Note object.
So that was my mistake, rookie mistake to be precise. Hope i helped some rookie like myself :)

Comment: Assuming `$request->getContent()` was the json object you posted, you could use `$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);` `$form->submit($data['noteForm']);` also assuming the `Note` object has public properties.

Comment: @fyrye It doesnt have public properties, but it has getters, so that works :) I worked it out, thank you for the answer. :)